# Is the usage of "extreme power" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

The intended meaning is "extremely strong power", but is it acceptable to omit "strong"?

*Extreme* means something akin to "at the very end of *xxx*", and *power* means "[ability to do or act](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/power?s=t)".

So, would saying "extreme power" mean "very strong power", or "weak OR strong power", or is it even grammatically correct?

For context: "He had *extreme power*, being able to punch that tree down."

Comment: It's going to depend on your context. For example:- (1) *only strong power structures have two extreme power levels, only they have "high power positions" and "low power positions.*" https://goo.gl/GtL6ba  and  (2) '*the case of a drug company which allegedly exercises the most extreme power - of life and death - over members of the public by marketing a dangerous drug*.'  https://goo.gl/aGxpfM

Answer (score 1):

To my ears, the phrase "extreme power" is not normally used to connote physical strength.

I think most native speakers would say one of the following:

> He was very strong...

or

> He had incredible/great/unimaginable/etc. strength...

In some circumstances, you might be able to get away with saying "He was extremely powerful", but that generally references a superhuman (i.e., comic book) strength.

Answer (score 0):

> He had extreme power, being able to punch that tree down.

Your example is correct usage of the phrase ***extreme power***.

It does not carry the connotation of *weak* as you ask in your question.

Generally speaking, nouns that have an intensive quality usually *strong* is usually **implied** when using the *extreme* intensifier. If you mean extremely *weak*, you usually have to explicitly state weak when using the *extreme* modifier.